# prometheus-adapter unable to fetch CPU metrics for pod podName skipping

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, prometheus, amazon-eks, prometheus-operator

We try to install Prometheus in AWS EKS through
[kube-prometheus](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus), However, we got an error for `kubectl top`  command.

```
kubectl top po -n monitoring
error: Metrics not available for pod monitoring/podName, age: 30h10m27.35393s
```

```
kubectl  top  node
error: metrics not available yet
```

After checking the logs of `prometheus-adapter`

Error logs as below

```
E0331 10:02:47.330109       1 provider.go:191] unable to fetch CPU metrics for pod beta/podName, skipping
E0331 10:02:47.346497       1 provider.go:191] unable to fetch CPU metrics for pod beta/podName, skipping
E0331 10:02:47.346540       1 provider.go:191] unable to fetch CPU metrics for pod beta/podName, skipping
```

Check the apiservice

```
kubectl get apiservice

v1beta1.events.k8s.io                  Local                           True        6d7h
v1beta1.extensions                     Local                           True        6d7h
v1beta1.flowcontrol.apiserver.k8s.io   Local                           True        6d7h
v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io                 monitoring/prometheus-adapter   True        26m
v1beta1.networking.k8s.io              Local                           True        6d7h
v1beta1.node.k8s.io                    Local                           True        6d7h
```

We know the `prometheus-adapter` is used for metrics now

The result of `kubectl get apiservice v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io -o yaml`

```
apiVersion: apiregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: APIService
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"apiregistration.k8s.io/v1","kind":"APIService","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app.kubernetes.io/component":"metrics-adapter","app.kubernetes.io/name":"prometheus-adapter","app.kubernetes.io/part-of":"kube-prometheus","app.kubernetes.io/version":"0.9.0"},"name":"v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io"},"spec":{"group":"metrics.k8s.io","groupPriorityMinimum":100,"insecureSkipTLSVerify":true,"service":{"name":"prometheus-adapter","namespace":"monitoring"},"version":"v1beta1","versionPriority":100}}
  creationTimestamp: "2022-03-31T11:28:00Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: metrics-adapter
    app.kubernetes.io/name: prometheus-adapter
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: kube-prometheus
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.9.0
  name: v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io
  resourceVersion: "2379238"
  uid: 570f7068-ea53-4850-ae65-6bf027457de1
spec:
  group: metrics.k8s.io
  groupPriorityMinimum: 100
  insecureSkipTLSVerify: true
  service:
    name: prometheus-adapter
    namespace: monitoring
    port: 443
  version: v1beta1
  versionPriority: 100
status:
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2022-03-31T11:28:31Z"
    message: all checks passed
    reason: Passed
    status: "True"
    type: Available
```

The metric reader configuration of Prometheus adapter

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: metrics-adapter
    app.kubernetes.io/name: prometheus-adapter
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: kube-prometheus
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.9.0
    rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aggregate-to-admin: "true"
    rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aggregate-to-edit: "true"
    rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aggregate-to-view: "true"
  name: system:aggregated-metrics-reader
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - metrics.k8s.io
  resources:
  - pods
  - nodes
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
```

The EKS version is `1.21` and prometheus-adapter is `v0.9.0`

Could someone help us to figure out the solution to this issue?

---

Update 04/06/2022:

After changing the instance to node in override in config map of Prometheus adapter. The errors are still here.

`kubectl get cm -n monitoring adapter-config -o yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  config.yaml: |-
    "resourceRules":
      "cpu":
        "containerLabel": "container"
        "containerQuery": |
          sum by (<<.GroupBy>>) (
            irate (
                container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{<<.LabelMatchers>>,container!="",pod!=""}[120s]
            )
          )
        "nodeQuery": |
          sum by (<<.GroupBy>>) (
            1 - irate(
              node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[60s]
            )
            * on(namespace, pod) group_left(node) (
              node_namespace_pod:kube_pod_info:{<<.LabelMatchers>>}
            )
          )
          or sum by (<<.GroupBy>>) (
            1 - irate(
              windows_cpu_time_total{mode="idle", job="windows-exporter",<<.LabelMatchers>>}[4m]
            )
          )
        "resources":
          "overrides":
            "namespace":
              "resource": "namespace"
            "node":
              "resource": "node"
            "pod":
              "resource": "pod"
      "memory":
        "containerLabel": "container"
        "containerQuery": |
          sum by (<<.GroupBy>>) (
            container_memory_working_set_bytes{<<.LabelMatchers>>,container!="",pod!=""}
          )
        "nodeQuery": |
          sum by (<<.GroupBy>>) (
            node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{job="node-exporter",<<.LabelMatchers>>}
            -
            node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes{job="node-exporter",<<.LabelMatchers>>}
          )
          or sum by (<<.GroupBy>>) (
            windows_cs_physical_memory_bytes{job="windows-exporter",<<.LabelMatchers>>}
            -
            windows_memory_available_bytes{job="windows-exporter",<<.LabelMatchers>>}
          )
        "resources":
          "overrides":
            "namespace":
              "resource": "namespace"
            "node":
              "resource": "node"
            "pod":
              "resource": "pod"
      "window": "5m"
kind: ConfigMap
```

Comment: Try with the prometheus-adapter version v0.9.1 and confirm.

Comment: @ChandraKiranPasumarti, same error with prometheus-adapter version v0.9.1

Comment: In the file custom-metrics-config-map.yaml, Try by changing the instance to node in overrides. 
'overrides:
            node:
              resource: node'

Comment: @ChandraKiranPasumarti, Thank you very much for your response. After changing the instance to node in override, the same errors are still here. More information has been updated to the question. Please correct me if something wrong.

Comment: Have you seen <https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/issues/247#issuecomment-518368336> <https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/prometheus-adapter/issues/398>?

Comment: @ChandraKiranPasumarti, thank you very much for your link. All methods in the link are tested in my EKS. Unfortunately, none of them work well...